# numpy dot or einsum with arbitrary operator

Tags: numpy, numpy-ufunc

I would like to use something like `np.dot` or (preferably) `np.einsum` to efficiently perform their same function but with an alternate `ufunc` instead of `np.multiply`. For example, consider these two arrays:

```
>>> a
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 0]])
>>> b
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 0]])
```

Now suppose I want to count the number of elements in each row of `a` equal to the corresponding elements in each row of `b`. I'd like to be able to do the equivalent of the following (note: the output below is fabricated but the values are what I would expect to see):

```
>>> np.dot(a, b.T, ufunc=np.equal)
array([[1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 2, 2, 1]])
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Would the arrays always have `0`s and `1`s only?

Comment: In my specific case, yes. But I'm curious about the answer for the more general case as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the broadcasting from Divakar's answer together with [numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr):

```
numexpr.evaluate('sum(1*(a == b), axis=2)', {'a': a[:,None]})
```

The `1*()` is [a workaround.](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/issues/96) I have confirmed this doesn't allocate a big temporary array.

Comment: And I thought slicing isn't supported with `numexpr`, good to know it does!

Comment: Well it's simply the `local_dict` argument, the slicing happens still happens in Python :-)

Comment: I think this will work best, as it avoids the temporary array storage. Upvote for @Divakar for an elegent numpy-only solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for such match counting problem -

```
(a[:,None] == b).sum(2)
```

Sample run -

```
In [36]: a
Out[36]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 0]])

In [37]: b
Out[37]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 0]])

In [38]: (a[:,None] == b).sum(2)
Out[38]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 2, 2, 1]])
```

If you really want to employ `np.einsum` and `np.equal`, here's a way to mold the earlier approach to give us the desired result -

```
np.einsum('ijk->ij',np.equal(a[:,None],b).astype(int))
```

Comment: That does produce the expected result. The one downside is the temporary storage for `(a[:,None] == b)` and `np.equal(a[:,None],b)`. In the example, the intermediate array has shape `(3, 4, 2)` but in practice, the last dimension may be large, which is why I was hoping to avoid it.

Comment: @bogatron What would be the typical shapes of `a`and `b` for the actual use case?

Comment: The first dimension of each array is around 10**5. The second dimension (over which the summation occurs) would be either 64 or 128.

Comment: @bogatron Well the boolean array of matches `a[:,None] == b` because of being boolean would be `8x` more efficient than int/float arrays. Even then if you get into memory issue, we could run a loop through the cols and do something like a[:,i,None]==b[:,i] and accumulate at each iteration. Other than those, I am out of ideas.

Comment: @Divakar - numexpr ;-) But you have to use `1*(a[:,None] == b)`, as [mentioned here](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/issues/96).

Comment: @user6758673 Good suggestion actually! That might speedup things specially on large arrays. OP should take note of it.

Comment: @Divakar - posted as a new answer

Answer (score 2):

There's an old issue on the numpy github asking for a generalization of `einsum` that would allow the use of other functions.  The current version just implements a sum of products.  As far as I know, no one has taken on that project.

Several years ago I patched `einsum`, fixing the handling of the '...' notation.  So I have a good idea of how it is implemented; and could probably adapt my Python/cython emulator to add this feature.  The actual `einsum` code is written in `c`.

My guess is that if you don't like Divakar's approach, you'll have to write your own version with `cython`.

Comment: The accepted answer does what I need but it would be great to see `einsum` support this feature. I've found it to run much faster than alternate solutions for numerous operations.

Comment: I was wondering myself, searching for this feature. It would be awesome if we could reuse the indexing machinery and flexible notation of einsum (and einops) AND also specify arbitrary (I guess commutative and associative ) binary operations instead of multiply for the terms and sum for the reduction. The thing I tried to implement was for example a meshgrid. What would be cool, would be to get each term in an einsum expression as another dimension in a resulting tensor.